# Как использовать несколько разных стилей для ToolTip в разных местах?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть два разных стиля для `ToolTip`.

Как использовать для одних элементов один стиль подсказки, а для других - другой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам придётся в явном виде задавать стиль в каждом случае:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Control.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="styNormalTooltip" TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".8"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="styTransparentTooltip" TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5"/>
        </Style>
    </Control.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Hello">
            <Button.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource styNormalTooltip}">Hello</ToolTip>
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="world!">
            <Button.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource styTransparentTooltip}">world!</ToolTip>
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Если вы считаете, что это слишком много кода, то, как обычно с XAML, вы можете воспользоваться attached properties, markup extensions, да даже конвертерами.